# git force push is changing username

Tags: git, github

When I did Git commit it got committed with UserA. But when I did Git push -f it shows "UserB force-pushed the UserA:branch_name branch from old_hash to new_hash"

So steps I did where:

```
-> Created branch from master (git checkout -b feature_branch master)
-> I did some changes and added the files, committed the code (git commit -m "some-message")
-> I did push (git push --set-upstream origin feature_branch)
-> Created a pull request. In Commits I see one commit and my name (git username)
-> I did some more changes added those files committed it (git commit --amend --no-edit)
-> then I did git push -f
So in the conversation tab, I see that UserB force-pushed the UserA:feature_branch branch from old_hash to new_hash
```

Here is git push -f output

```
Enumerating objects: 25, done.
Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.46 KiB | 498.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (12/12), completed with 12 local objects.
To https://github.com/<username or UserA>/<reponame>.git
 + e769b1c3c...864f02325 feature_name -> feature_name (forced update)
```

I checked keychain access is also UserA login and git config --global also shows UserA config.

So how can I make this force push to UserA but not UserB?

Comment: May you edit the question and share example git commands you're using and their output?

Comment: I've added the steps I did

Comment: When you `git push -f` what did it say on the prompt?

Comment: git push -f is normal forced push from this -> to branch-name

Comment: @PuneetMehta that's not very helpful? Please may you share the output after you ran the command?

Comment: I've updated git push -f response

Comment: JYI no where it is saying User B

Comment: Please double check that your git config details are correct? `git config --list`